# Trouble installing Swift in GitHub Actions Ubuntu

Tags: swift, ubuntu, github, github-actions

I'm unable to successfully install and run Swift on GitHub Actions on Ubuntu.

Here's my Actions code:

```
name: SwiftPlot Ubuntu

on:
  push:
    branches: master
  pull_request:

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Install Freetype
      run: sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev
    - name: Install Swift Dependencies
      run: sudo apt-get install clang libicu-dev
    - name: Download Swift
      run: wget "https://swift.org/builds/swift-5.1.3-release/ubuntu1804/swift-5.1.3-RELEASE/swift-5.1.3-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04.tar.gz"
    - name: Install Swift
      run: |
        tar xzf swift-5.1.3-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04.tar.gz
        export PATH=$(pwd)/swift-5.1.3-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04/usr/bin:"${PATH}"
    - name: Build
      run: swift build -v
    - name: Run tests
      run: swift test -v
```

But it's unable to find `swift`. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting environment variables with `export` does not work in GitHub Actions. There is a special function you can use to add a path instead.

See the documentation for `add-path` [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/development-tools-for-github-actions#add-a-system-path-add-path).

```
    - name: Install Swift
      run: |
        tar xzf swift-5.1.3-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04.tar.gz
        echo "::add-path::$(pwd)/swift-5.1.3-RELEASE-ubuntu18.04/usr/bin"
```